# How to fix the TYPO3 Password Reminder Error

Tags: passwords, typo3, typo3-9.x

after the last updates up to 9.5.8 all users get the message after login that they should change their password, for me as an admin that works just fine but all other users, once they hit "ok" on the popup receive an error which outputs the following

`typo3/undefined`

its also not an error in the typical typo3 style or something, more like a full blank page with that text on in.

i tried to simulate one of that users and i was not able to find a general section if a user wants to change the password, is that because im simulating the user or are there some access rights missing that prevent the user from changing his password?  and if yes, can this be the reason for the password reminder not to work?

any ideas? help is much appreciated.

Comment: There is no such functionality in TYPO3. Please check your 3rd party extensions for this. Aside from that this sounds suspicious ...

Comment: Do you have [EXT:be_secure_pw](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/be_secure_pw/) installed?

Comment: If you have be_secure_pw installed, which version do you use and has the user access to his user settings? After clicking "ok" in the popup it redirects to the user settings module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reminder is nothing but a link to the User-Settings section. The Privilege was not granted and that was the reason for the Typo3/undefined error. We activated the access to User-Settings for our users and now the reminder works just fine.